# Why am I unable to fetch metric values for EC2 instances from cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get the cloudwatch metric data for CPU Utilazation of an EC2 instance i-014448f54423cc0, but i am getting the following output without any metrics data

**AWS CLI COMMAND**

```
$ aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2017-03-20T23:18:00 --end-time 2017-03-25T23:18:00 --period 3600 --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=i-014448f54423cc0,Value=i-abcdef
```

**OUTPUT**

```
-----------------------------
|    GetMetricStatistics    |
+--------+------------------+
|  Label |  CPUUtilization  |
+--------+------------------+
```

As per the following thread on AWS forum: [Link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=249247)
It is said that cloudwatch metrics data can be accessed through API's only if detailed monitoring is enabled, so I tried both scenarios of with & without enabling detailed monitoring but still in both the cases the output is same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined your dimension incorrectly. The dimension you are filtering (literally 'InstanceId') needs to be defined as the `Name`, and your value (in this case, the instance id's value) as the `Value`.

### Example

**Snippet:**

```
Name=InstanceId,Value=i-014448f54423cc0
```

**Full example:**

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2017-03-20T23:18:00 --end-time 2017-03-25T23:18:00 --period 3600 --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-014448f54423cc0
```

### Discussion

The linked AWS forum discussion isn't relevant to this situation, because detailed monitoring only enables monitoring at 1-minute granularity. Basic monitoring samples data on five-minute intervals. Since you are requesting CPUUtilization for each hour (period=3600 seconds) on a single instance, you will have data available with no need for detailed monitoring.

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - Enable or Disable Detailed Monitoring for Your Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch-new.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Amazon EC2 Metrics and Dimensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ec2-metricscollected.html)
- [AWS Documentation - AWS CLI get-metric-statistics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html)

Comment: Still same Output, Despite using `Name=InstanceId,Value=i-014448f54423cc0`

Comment: @karthikvee The given example, replacing the value for an instance of my own, yields the expected results in my console. Sanity check a few other details: Is your InstanceId correct? Are you querying in the correct region? Do the AWS credentials you've provided to the CLI have permission to get metrics for this instance?

Comment: Ah! finally! I got the output! Ty.. I was using wrong Region

Comment: Great! No problem, happy to help.